# Rails Join - How to get fields with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, outer-join

I have two tables with same name and am doing a join

```
Visits::Appointment
    name:string
    id:integer
    ...


Places::Seatables
    name:string
    appointment_id:integer
    id:integer
    ....
```

I want to do a outer join and get all the fields. I am getting only the name and id from the seatable table when I do the following.

```
  Visits::Appointment.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN places_seatables ON  places_seatables.appointment_id=visits_appointments.id").where('checkout is null and "isActive" is true and noshow is false').select(visits_appointments.*,places_seatables.*')
```

How can I get both the fields instead of just one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
appointments = Visits::Appointment
               .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN places_seatables ON  places_seatables.appointment_id=visits_appointments.id")
               .where('checkout is null and "isActive" is true and noshow is false')
               .select(visits_appointments.*,places_seatables.name as seatable_name, places_seatables.id as seatable_id')
```

Now you can access them as

```
appointment = appointments.first
appointment.seatable_name
appointment.seatable_id
```

Comment: Thanks...How do you order by name?

Comment: To do the order by asc just append `.order('name asc')`

Comment: I know this an old answer, but why do you use double quotes, single quotes and no quotes on each part of the query?